# What kind of encoding is this: \x3Cb\x3E\x3C?

Tags: java, ajax, text, encoding

I'm receiving data from an AJAX request, and it's really weird. I thought it was unicode, but unicode's codes are like \u00E7 (ç).

```
\x3Cb\x3E\x3C
```

What do you think this is? And how can I convert it to normal text with Java?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It might be plain ASCII. `\x3Cb\x3E\x3C` decodes to `<b><`.

Comment: What are you familiar with? C++, C#, PHP, Python, anything would work. I can't find the solution on the internet. How did you decode it so fast?

Comment: I found the solution here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3775684/decoding-html-returned-as-json-response-android/3776170#3776170

Comment: I typed `javascript:alert('\x3Cb\x3E\x3C');` in browser's address bar ;) It is a way to escape symbols, "\" is escape character, `x` means that next 2 symbols are char code in HEX, so `\x3C` is `chr(0x3C)` or `chr(60)`, which results in "<" symbol.

Answer (score -1):

html entities it is. So you have html content embedded in your ajax hash.
what language you are using? there should be several encode/decode anyway. RoR has it for sure, in .NET is use the JSON.NET lib to decode.

Comment: it has nothing to do with HTML entities. HTML entities start with `&`, end with `;` and have either name of entity between those chars (e.g., `&amp;` or `&apos;`) or `#` sign after `&`, followed by char code (e.g., `&#65;` or `&#x41;` for letter "A").