# Decoding javascript escape sequences in PHP (\x27, \x22, etc...)

Tags: php, javascript, decode

If I have this PHP string:

```
$string = '\\x27\\x22';
```

How would I decode it to `'"`?

Comment: `preg_replace_callback('#\\\\x([a-f0-9]{2})#i', function($matches) { return chr(hexdec($matches[1])); }, $input);`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Interpret escape characters in single quoted string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8309731/interpret-escape-characters-in-single-quoted-string)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to convert hex codes in JSON data using PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11692110/how-to-convert-hex-codes-in-json-data-using-php)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A regex could help you here:

```
$out = preg_replace_callback(
  "(\\\\x([0-9a-f]{2}))i",
  function($a) {return chr(hexdec($a[1]));},
  $string
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to decode it. Just do `str_replace('\\x27', "'", $str);`. In case your `'"` was just and example, please note you got repeatable pattern `\\xAA`, where `x` indicates hexadecimal notation and `AA` is hex value itself, so each `\\xAA` represents single byte and `AA` is from 0 to 0xFF. So you can use regexp or just walk any other way over your string, extract these `AA` values and convert it with `chr(hexdec($AA))` to coresponding characted and glue with result string.

Comment: For every single possible escape sequence?

Comment: No :) I edited my answer while you was writting your comment.

Answer (score 0):

```
$out = preg_replace_callback(
  "(\\\\x([0-9a-f]{2}))i",
  function($a) {return '\u00'.bin2hex(hex2bin($a[1]));},
  $string
);
```

That's ok after I converted the value from ascii to unicode.