# How to revert HTML encoding?

Tags: php, html, regex

I am working in PHP and I have a string in html , saved in database, which is encoded like this

```
\x3cdiv class\x3d\x22hdtb-mn-cont\x22\x3e\x3cdiv id\x3d\x22XJDHvf\x22\x3e\x3c/div\x3e\x3cdiv class\x3d\x22hdtb-mn-hd\x22
```

I have tried a lot to decode it. For example `\x3cdiv` wil become `"<div"` but couldn't find any specific function. Can someone please help?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6465263/how-to-reverse-htmlentities/6465281

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11692110/how-to-convert-hex-codes-in-json-data-using-php

Comment: @DarrenH thanks for your help bro. I was unable to figure out what type of encoding it is. Thats why posted it.