# How to receive an index and display its ASCII character?

Tags: java, ascii

I have an input of a number (0-127), and want to display the ASCII character with that index. So far, I have only achieved this with my own variable. Could someone please explain how to do this with an input instead?

My code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class CharCode {
    public static void main (String [] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        // obtain index
        System.out.print("Enter an ASCII code: ");
        String entry = input.next();
        // How do I get a char with the inputted ASCII index here?

        // I can do it with my own variable, but not with input:
        int i = 97;
        char c = (char) i; // c is now equal to 'a'
        System.out.println(c);
    }
}
```

Comment: What's wrong with your current code? Also why is all of your code left justified? Is that how you format all of your code? Since you're asking volunteers to give free help, please understand that we greatly appreciate you're putting in effort to make it easier to help you, like posting well-formatted easy to read code.

Comment: What is the problem you are encountering?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/833709/converting-int-to-char-in-java

That link has several examples.

Comment: If I'm interpreting the OP correctly, I think she may be saying that so far she has tried this with the "i" variable, but is having problems when trying to use user input.

Comment: `System.out.println((char)input.nextInt());`

Comment: Thank you for your help.  and yes Hyper Anthony, that is where I was having trouble.

Comment: @AlishaMcDonald Good to hear.  If smit's answer was what you were looking for, be sure to click the check icon to the left of his answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want to enter user any ASCII value and it will be showed in char value. For that you need to change as you have to do these operations on user input.

```
int entry = input.nextInt(); // get the inputted number as integer
// and
char c = (char) entry;
```

**OR**

For your current implementation

```
//entry has to be String of numbers otherwise it will throw NumberFormatException.
char c = (char) (Integer.parseInt(entry)); // c will contain 'a'
```

Comment: Thank you so much.  Now it makes perfect sense