# How do I convert a user-input integer into a char ASCII value in java?

Tags: java, casting, ascii

I am trying to make a program where you can enter a credit card number and it will spit out the number back at you with a ASCII letter/symbol on the end using the remainder of the added digits divided by 26. I feel like my code is right although when I run the program, no symbol shows up. I do not get debug errors or anything, but my (char) symbol just doesn't show up. All it shows is the numbers. Can someone help me please?

Here is what I have so far:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.text.*;
import java.math.*;

public class Program{

public static void main (String []args){

Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

int CC, CC2, CC3, CC4;


System.out.println("Enter your credit card number 2 numbers at a time (XX XX XX XX)");
CC=keyboard.nextInt();
CC2=keyboard.nextInt();
CC3=keyboard.nextInt();
CC4=keyboard.nextInt();

 int CC6;

CC6= (CC+CC4+CC2+CC3)%26;

char CC7;

CC7 = (char)CC6;


System.out.println("The correct number and code is:" +CC+CC2+CC3+CC4+CC7);    

}
}
```

Comment: Can you post expected input/output?

Comment: Pro tip: If you're using Eclipse, pressing Ctrl+Shift+F will format your code nicely, and pressing Ctrl+Shift+O will clean up your imports. Consider doing that before posting!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Print them separately and you can see some weird symbol coming in the console.

```
System.out.println("The correct number and code is:" + CC + CC2 + CC3 + CC4);
System.out.println(CC7);
```

The thing is, you'll get the CC7 in the range of 0-25 only since you're doing a *mod 26* and this range contains ASCII codes of non-character keys.

Actual character(or for that case, special characters) start from ASCII code `33`. Have a look at the [ASCII table](http://www.asciitable.com/) here.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you're looking for

```
Character.toChars(CC6);
```

Make sure that when you're testing, you're using a value which actually maps to a decent looking value. For example `Character.toChars(65)` results in 'A'.

For further reference, see: [Converting stream of int's to char's in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/833709/converting-int-to-char-in-java)

Comment: When I tried that it just gave me the number instead of the character?

`code`

CC6= ((CC+CC4+CC2+CC3)%26)+65;
    
      Character.toChars(CC6);
    
    

System.out.println("The correct number and code is:" +CC+CC2+CC3+CC4);    
    System.out.println(+CC6);

Comment: `Character.toChars(int)` returns a `char[]`. You need to either store it somewhere, or use it directly in the `println`.

Answer (score 0):

There is a character there its just one that isnt display well with the console. Probably being rendered as a blank space. I see you are using the remainder of 26 so im guessing you want it to be a letter (a-z). The ascii characters for letters start at 65 for capitals and 97 for lower case.

Make this change

```
CC6= (CC+CC4+CC2+CC3)%26+65;
```

and you will see a letter between A and Z being printed out.

You can view the full ASCII table here http://www.asciitable.com/