# Sign frequency, highest frequency, number of signs

Tags: java, ascii, frequency, sign

Java. Converting a string into its ASCII code equivalent and:

```
public class Loop {
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        BralecPodatkov bp = new BralecPodatkov();     // allows me to write string
        System.out.println("Type string: ");
        String niz = bp.beriNiz();                    // reads my string
        int[] frequencies = new int [128];     // all 128 ASCII signs
        int total = 0;

        System.out.println("N of signs: " + niz.length());     // sum of all signs

        for (int i = 0; i < niz.length(); i++) {
            int ascii = (int) niz.charAt(i);
                frequencies[ascii]++;
                total += 1;
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < frequencies.length; i++) {
            if (frequencies[i] > 0)
                System.out.print(" " + (((float) frequencies[i]/total)*100) + "%");
          else
                System.out.print(" 0%");     // prints all sign frequencies in %
        }               

        int max = frequencies[0];
        for (int i = 0; i < niz.length(); i++) {
            if (frequencies[i] > max) {
                max = frequencies[i];     // print sign with highest frequency
            }
        }
    System.out.println("\n" + "Max number: " + max);     
    }
}
```

Result:

```
Type string: 
1234               // arbitrary string that I insert
N of signs: 4
 0% 0% 0% 0% 0% 0% 0% 0% 0% 0% 0% 0% 0% 0% 0% 0% 0% 0% 0% 0% 0% 0% 0% 0% 0% 0% 0% 0% 0% 0% 0% 0% 0% 0% 0% 0% 0% 0% 0% 0% 0% 0% 0% 0% 0% 0% 0% 0% 0% 25.0% 25.0% 25.0% 25.0% 0% 0% 0% 0% 0% 0% 0% 0% 0% 0% 0% 0% 0% 0% 0% 0% 0% 0% 0% 0% 0% 0% 0% 0% 0% 0% 0% 0% 0% 0% 0% 0% 0% 0% 0% 0% 0% 0% 0% 0% 0% 0% 0% 0% 0% 0% 0% 0% 0% 0% 0% 0% 0% 0% 0% 0% 0% 0% 0% 0% 0% 0% 0% 0% 0% 0% 0% 0% 0% 0% 0% 0% 0% 0% 0%
Max number: 0
```

Code to read a string and print out: the sum of all signs, the frequency of every sign (in %) and the sign with the highest frequency.
Questions:
1) How can I add the appropriate sign before each frequency? (e.g. 1 = 25%, 2 = 25%, ...)
2) My max number frequency code is not working, it always prints out 0. What am I doing wrong?
3) How to count the number of unique signs of the string?

Also if you find any mistakes, complications or have any comments do let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1 - Has been answered before [Converting stream of int's to char's in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/833709/converting-int-to-char-in-java)

```
for (int i = 0; i < frequencies.length; i++) {
        System.out.print( Character.toChars(i) );
        System.out.print( " = ");
        if (frequencies[i] > 0)
```

2 - The max counting has a typo:

```
    int max = frequencies[0];
    for (int i = 0; i < niz.length(); i++) {
```

Use `frequencies.length` instead of niz.length().

3 - Not sure what you are asking. The unique characters in the input string? Just see if `frequencies[i] > 0` in the max loop would work.

Comment: 1 - so I've read the link and... either I did not find my answer or the answer was too complicated. Could you elaborate?

Comment: 2 - does not seem to work, it prints out random small numbers