# In java why we can't assign int to char directly??? but vice-versa is true?

Tags: java

```
public class CharAndIntTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        char i='1';
        int ii=65;
        i=ii;
    }

}
```

Comment: Have a look at [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/833709/converting-int-to-char-in-java)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`char`s are 16-bit unsigned numbers, so they got a maximum of `65,635`.
`int`s are 32-bit signed numbers,s o they got a maximum of `2,147,483,647`.

So something is bound to go wrong if you sign an `int` to a `char`, for all values `>= 65,635`.

Comment: @kviiri My bad, mixed up the signs, fixed now.

Answer (score 8):

An `int` has larger capacity than a `char`, so the conversion is not guaranteed to work. The possible range in the value of a `char` is 0 to 65535, but an `int` can be anywhere from -2147483648 to 2147483647.

However, there are other considerations other than raw storage size. `char` is an unsigned type (Java's only built-in unsigned type, actually), so even `short` and `byte` variables still need a conversion to `char` as they may be negative. `short` and `char` are both 16 bit, but since `short` is signed its range is different from that of `char` (range of `short` being from -32,768 to 32,767).

The most important thing to learn here is that **Java only lets implicit conversions take place if it can be absolutely determined that the conversion will succeed.** This applies to primitives, objects, generics, and pretty much everything.

You can force the conversion to happen using a cast:

```
char i='1';
int ii=65;
i=(char)ii; //explicit cast tells the compiler to force the int into a char
```

Comment: Then short's size is same as that of char but then also compiler is giving error for that

Answer (score 6):

The assignment conversion ([JLS, Section 5.2](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.2)) allows a primitive widening conversion, but not a primitive narrowing conversion:

> Assignment conversion occurs when the value of an expression is
>   assigned (§15.26) to a variable: the type of the expression must be
>   converted to the type of the variable.
>
> Assignment contexts allow the use of one of the following:
>
> - an identity conversion (§5.1.1)
> - a widening primitive conversion (§5.1.2)
> - a widening reference conversion (§5.1.5)
> - a boxing conversion (§5.1.7) optionally followed by a widening
>     reference conversion
> - an unboxing conversion (§5.1.8) optionally followed by a widening
>     primitive conversion.

So you must cast to perform a primitive narrowing conversion, unless

> In addition, if the expression is a constant expression (§15.28) of
>   type byte, short, char, or int:
>
> - A narrowing primitive conversion may be used if the type of the
>     variable is byte, short, or char, and the value of the constant
>     expression is representable in the type of the variable.

So assigning a literal will work:

```
char a = 65;
```

Comment: +1 this applies even if the "wider" type is smaller, e.g. a 64-bit long can be assigned to a 32-bit float. i.e. range matters not precision.

Comment: short size and char size is same though it will giving an error message then

Answer (score 1):

A `char` is a 16-bit datatype while an `int` is a 32-bit datatype. Thus, some possible `int` values can't be represented with a `char` without dropping some data (truncation). The compiler creates an error message to warn you about the possible problems caused by accidental truncation.

You can still assign `int` values to `char` if you do the appropriate casting:

```
int i=500;
char c = (char)i;
```

You can even assign illegal `char` values like this, although the result will still be truncated:

```
int i = 65555;
char c = (char)i; //still compiles and doesn't cause an exception, but data is lost
i = c; //i's value is 19
```