# java why char to short is possible in method return type

Tags: java, methods, casting, char, short

I have the following method in Java:

```
private static short charToShort_1() {
    return 's';
}

private static char shortToChar_1() {
    return ((short) 15);
}

private static short charToShort_2() {
    char ch = 's';
    return ch;
}

private static char shortToChar_2() {
    short number = 15;
    return number;
}
```

Why "charToShort_1" and "shortToChar_1" are compiled successfully?
In the same time the last two methods "charToShort_2" and "shortToChar_2" can not be compiled (because explicit cast is necessary).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5058859/short-and-char-type-in-java

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20500676/in-java-why-we-cant-assign-int-to-char-directly-but-vice-versa-is-true

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here  :

```
private static short charToShort_1() {
    return 's';
}
```

`'s'` is a constant expression and this value is representable in `short`. 
So the compiler does an implicit conversion.

The [JLS](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.2-300) states :

> In addition, if the expression is a constant expression (§15.28) of
>   type byte, short, char, or int:
>
> - A narrowing primitive conversion may be used if the type of the
>     variable is byte, short, or char, and the value of the constant
>     expression is representable in the type of the variable.

The `short` values range is  `-32,768` to `32,767` (inclusive).
So a constant expression `char` out of these bounds will produce a compilation error :

```
private static short charToShort_2() {
   return '耀'; // 32768 numeric value       
}
```

About this method that doesn't compile  :

```
private static short charToShort_2() {
    char ch = 's';
    return ch;
}
```

`char ch = 's';` is not a constant expression.
You **may** reassign `ch` with a new `char` value that is not representable in `short` (such as `'耀'` that is represented by the `32768` numeric value).
So the compiler expects you explicitly cast it to `short` as the conversion 
may be a narrowing primitive conversion.
Change it into a `final` variable and you will see that it compiles fine :

```
private static short charToShort_2() {
    final char ch = 's';
    return ch;
}
```

About this method that casts from `short` to `char`, the compilation error reason is exactly the same as for `charToShort_2()`

At last, about `shortToChar_1()` :

```
private static char shortToChar_1() {
    return ((short) 15);
}
```

The cast to short may give the impression that you spend less memory than if you had used a `int`:

```
private static char shortToChar_1() {
    return 15;
}
```

In fact, it doesn't change anything as in both cases the compiler will use the [`bipush`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_bytecode_instruction_listings) JVM instruction to push a `byte` onto the stack as an integer value.

Answer (score 1):

The real answer lies in this statement from §5.2 of the [Java Language Specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html) (for Java 8, but applies to previous versions as well)

> In addition, if the expression is a constant expression (§15.28) of type byte, short, char, or int:
>
> A narrowing primitive conversion may be used if the type of the variable is byte, short, or char, and the value of the constant expression is representable in the type of the variable.

So constant expressions are treated specially in that they allow some narrowing conversions that are disallowed for other expressions.

Answer (score 0):

3 and 4 method are wrong because this transformation is narrowing (with loss of data). You must explicitly indicate that you understand and agree with all the risks associated with this transformation.

5.1.3 paragraph
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se6/html/conversions.html

Answer (score 0):

**The answer is pretty sinple because char is the unsigned data type in java whereas short is signed data type,so there is no implicit conversion for it in java**

according to the [Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html)

> char to short is a narrowing primitive conversion

Comment: Thank you.<br>Then, why "charToShort_1" and "shortToChar_1" are compiled successfully? 's' is just a char but the method return_type is short (for charToShort_1).

Comment: 's' is not a char

Comment: its just a constant