# Casting from an int to char

Tags: java, casting

so I want to cast from an integer to a character, like 65 to A, but when I do                                                                                                                `System.out.println((char)65);`
it prints out in eclipse a box with a question mark in it.
How can I cast from an int to a char? Thanks!

Comment: This question has about 12 million results. Google first.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Converting int to char in java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/833709/converting-int-to-char-in-java)

Comment: What exactly do you want to achieve from this cast ?

Comment: @Jabir - I think he wants to print "A" on the console

Comment: This works on the command line and Eclipse.

Comment: It should run properly on cmd line. Try it. And on eclipse, there is some problem with showing the char.

Answer (score 1):

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    char c = (char) 65;
    System.out.println(c);
}
```

O/P : A

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    //char c = (char) 65;
    System.out.println((char)65 );
}
```

O/ P : A

Its working right?. This should work. Check your character encoding.