# How can I convert an int into a char datatype in java?

Tags: java, int, character

```
int i=2;
```

From that int datatype ,I wan to convert it into char data type .

I want to convert it so that I can do validation check like Character.isDigit(i)
  As in I want to make the 2 into '2' char type while maintaining the original value.
  All the answers given below is to convert it into the character based on ASCII code.
  What I want is the exact conversion of the original value of the int.

Comment: Try this. http://bit.ly/1pvCreL

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1114741/how-to-convert-int-to-char-c may help.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Converting int to char in java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/833709/converting-int-to-char-in-java)

Comment: It is unclear whether you want the character `'2'` or the character `'\002'`.

Comment: @David Conrad I want the '2',original value of the int ,not the conversion based on ASCII code.

Comment: If you're trying to tell if the `int` was a single digit, why not just use `if (i >= 0 && i <= 9)`?

Comment: @DavidConrad I need to check multi value digit as well.After reading your suggestion,I just remembered char could not accept more than 1 digit .Thanks man I guess I have to convert it into String first.

Comment: What is a 'multi value digit'? There's no such thing. That's not what the word "digit" means. I guess you're trying to check whether a number is numeric? What value of an `int` could you possibly convert to a `String` that would ***not*** be numeric?

Comment: @DavidConrad I'm creating an menu interface that is able to display a list of customers,e.g. 1)John 2)Jack .So in order to prevent user from entering other non-numeric value such as alphabet.I have to check whether it is an digit before proceeding to the subsequents steps to prevent errors.

Answer (score 2):

How can I convert an int into a char datatype in java?

```
   static int i = 2;
    char c = (char) i;

    System.out.println(c);
```

this typecasting method will  print Unicode tough.

```
char dig = Character.forDigit(2, 10);
```

This will print the required result that is 2.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`Character.forDigit`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#forDigit%28int,%20int%29) method:

```
int num = 2;
char dig = Character.forDigit(2, 10);
```

This gives you a representation of your number as a single-digit character.

Answer (score 0):

> How can I convert an int into a char datatype in java?

Your question isn't entirely clear,

```
int i = 2;
```

Assuming you want '2', you could use

```
int i = 2;
char ch = (char) ('0' + i);
System.out.println(ch);
```

**Edit**

> I have to check whether it is an digit before proceeding to the subsequents steps to prevent errors.

Then you could use [`Character.isDigit(char)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#isDigit%28char%29) -

```
char ch = '0';
if (Character.isDigit(ch)) {
  System.out.println("is digit");
} else {
  System.out.println("is NOT digit");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to convert it using the `forDigit()` method of `Character`.

`char c = Character.forDigit(i, 10);`

This will convert `i` to a `Char` value.

Comment: The OP asked how to convert it to a `char`, not a `String`.

Comment: Well I definitely missed that... LOL

Answer (score 0):

Do the following

```
int i = 2;
char c = (char) i
```

Comment: A `char` is not a `String`.

Comment: But the OP asked for a `char`, not a `String`.

Comment: @DavidConrad when I commented, the poster was using `Integer.toString()`