# Storing Integer value as A Character Java

Tags: java, integer, character

I tried to look in previous stack overflow questions but could not find any similar.

I want to store the integer value to char variable but the integer value is stored in another variable.

```
    char[] ch1 = (binary1.toString()).toCharArray();
    char[] ch2 = binary2.toString().toCharArray();

    if (ch1.length >= ch2.length) {

        char[] ch = new char[ch1.length];
        int j = 0;
        int num1;
        int num2;
        int num3;

        for (int i = 0; i < ch1.length; i++) {

            if (j == ch2.length - 1)
                j = 0;

            num1 = Character.getNumericValue(ch1[i]);
            num2 = Character.getNumericValue(ch2[j]);
            num3 = num1 ^ num2;

            ch[i] = (char) num3;

            j++;
        }
        String str = new String(ch);

        return str;

    }
```

Here what is happening is that I am getting null values in many cases.
I tried to look in the Character class but could not find any function.

If there is any way then please tell.
Thanks in advance.

EDIT : I need to store either 0 or 1

EDIT : ch1[] & ch2[] ar of char type

**EDIT** : I got a temporary solution to my problem but for a wider concept how should we type cast integer to char if size is same and when getting null values.

Comment: can you explain "I want to store the integer value to char variable but the integer value is stored in another variable." better?

Comment: More code please, print ch1[i] and ch2[j] and you will probably see your mistake.

Comment: I mean if the number is given directly I could have stored it in the char using '' but it is stored in another variable as shown above and I need to type cast to char and thus having problem

Comment: @FINDarkside The code is having problem in the line char ch = (char)num3; before that it is correct, I have checked.

Comment: And what is the variable, more code please... What is the type of ch1[i]?

Comment: character is 2 bytes and integer is 4 bytes, when you want to down cast it, not sure if you can get the correct value

Comment: @Arkantos But I have to store just 1 or 0, is there any possible way?

Comment: We don't have any idea of what you're trying to achieve. Please explain it better.

Comment: so are you absolutely sure that num3 will be always 1 or 0 ?

Comment: @Arkantos, yeah I am using xor operation. And why do people downvote, its not as if the question was asked before?

Comment: @JBNizet I just want to know how to convert integer to char in the line char ch = (char)num3; where I am getting null values many times. And please don't downvote, I have asked quite clearly.

Comment: A primitive int and a primitive char can't be null. I don't see how you could get null values. That doesn't make any sense. Provide a reproducible test case, explain what you expect the code to do, and what it does instead.

Comment: Exactly.. `char ch = (char)num3;` in that `ch` cannot be null as it's not a reference but a primitive value

Comment: @JBNizet the above code is working in loop and as you can see I am calculating the xor value and storing in num3 and from there I am storing in the char array ch.

Comment: @JB Nizet I think that it wont be null but it's whitespace character.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do

```
char ch = num3 == 0 ? '0' : '1';
```

Comment: Yeah I need to store 0 or 1.

Comment: @Arqam Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: @FINDarkside Yeah this looks good. Please upvote the question as I have got one downvote and I will be blocked now.

Comment: If you ever need to extract any other single digit int as a character, you can try `String.valueOf(num).charAt(0)`, works but kind of overkill :)

Comment: Looks like there's even a better way of doing this... forDigit() on Character class, `Character.forDigit(9,10)` returns `'9'` - 1st argument int, 2nd argument radix

Answer (score 0):

When you  call `Character.getNumericValue(someChar)`; You are actually getting the integer literal of the value.

Lets say `someChar='4';` in this case, The above method will give you a value 4.

But you cannot get numaric value if the char has value other than 0 to 9

If you really want the integer value of what so ever byte value stored in the char variable, then you have to type cast it directly to an integer as below.

```
char x = 'Z';
int z = x;
System.out.println(z);
```

the above code snippet will print 90 as Z is equalent to 90 in ascii.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your conversion from 
`char ch = (char)num3;` is not right?

Maybe you can try to use something like
`Character.toChars(65)`

See this answer for information on that:[Converting stream of int's to char's in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/833709/converting-int-to-char-in-java)

Comment: That will give me the character at that ascii value. I just wanted to store the integer as it is in the character variable.

Answer (score 0):

If you know that your integer is a single digit number, then you can use Character's `forDigit` method to do the conversion from `int` to `char`

```
Character.forDigit(9,10) --> '9'
```

From the Official [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#forDigit(int,%20int)),

> Determines the character representation for a specific digit in the
>   specified radix.

**Parameters:**

- digit - the number to convert to a character.
- radix - the radix.

**Returns:**

the char representation of the specified digit in the specified radix.